# Proving a combinatorial identity: $\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{2i}2^{n-2i}=\frac{3^n++1}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n=2k$ if $n$ is even, and $n=2k+1$ if $n$ is odd, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then prove:

> $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{2i}2^{n-2i}=\frac{3^n++1}{2}$$

I know that the binomial expansion of $(2+1)^n$ should help, but how exactly?

Comment: Please check the numerator on the right hand side of the equation for a typographical error.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I was thinking perhaps it's written like that on purpose to suggest using $+1$ and $-1$?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{3^n++1}2&=&\frac{(2+1)^n+(2-1)^n}2\\
&=&\frac12\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj2^{n-j}(+1)^j+\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj2^{n-j}(-1)^j\right)\\
&=&\sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{2i}2^{n-2i}\;.\\
\end{eqnarray}